# Убрать /index.php в середине url через htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, чпу

`foo.com/index.phpcontact/` открывает страницу ( ответ 200 ), также, как и 
`foo.com/contact/`

Если открыть `foo.com/index.phpcontact` выдаст 404

`foo.com/index.php/contact/` 301 убирает хорошо на `foo.com/contact/`

Стоит WordPress 4.4.8
в htaccess прописано:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ foo.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Шел конфликт из-за плагина `WP Super Cache` ( отключил его )

Вместо редиректа, плагин подставлял кеш.

Для надежности в `index.php` прописал убрать `/`

```
// Получаем URI для проверки 
   $uri = preg_replace("/\?.*/i",'', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);   
   if (strlen($uri)>1) {// если не главная страница...   
     if (rtrim($uri,'/')!=$uri) {
       header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
       header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].str_replace($uri, rtrim($uri,'/'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    exit();       
} }
```

Answer (score -2):

Удалить весь этот мусор и, зайдя в настройки ЧПУ, дать возможность ВП самому сгенерировать htaccess.